# Как назначить событие на динамически добавляющейся объект?

Tags: jquery, события, javascript

Есть дерево элементов, которое выглядит по принципу

```
<div class="top"></div>
<div class="under"></div>
<div class="top"></div>
<div class="under"></div>
<div class="top"></div>
<div class="under"></div>
```

При клике на топ должен сворачиваться андер, при этом топ и андер динамически добавляются
и их может быть неограниченное количество. Как это можно реализовать?

Я сначала не учел то, что топ и андер могут добавляться. Делал через делегирование событий, повесил один обработчик клик, который определял класс топ, в итоге при клике на топ сворачивались все соответственно. Потом циклом проходил по всем элементам класса, и так как порядок элемента класса топ должен совпадать с порядком элемента андер делал примерно такое:

`$('.top')[i].click(function(){
   $('.under')[i].toggle();
});`

Comment: мб вы имеете ввиду событие $.live()  ???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$('.top').click(function(){
    $(this).next().hide(200);
});
```

Пример: http://jsfiddle.net/DTe7M/

Answer (score 2):

а вообще

```
$('.top').click(function(){
   $(this).next('.under').toggle();
});
```

и при каждом добавлении просто вызывать эту фигню...

ps; ошибочку поправил :) забыл `next` написать :)

Answer (score 0):

В вашем вопросе не хватает.... проблемы?

Проблемы нет - [delegate](http://api.jquery.com/delegate/)

Первый пример в вашу тему

Comment: Я не совсем понял, under и top если и создаются - то вместе и мне нужно чтобы при клике на top сворачивался under который именно под top, как мне определить этот under?

Comment: `$(this).next('.under')` ?